# Probability a study rejects the null hypothesis

Tags: statistics

I have the following question but am not too sure how to approach it:

"A researcher is interested in knowing whether early childhood education has an impact on graduate earnings. She finds 9 published studies that have tested the null hypothesis that there is no impact. Since the studies were conducted at different times in different countries, it is reasonable to assume that the samples are statistically independent.

Assuming that there is in fact no relationship between early childhood education and graduate earnings, what is the probability that at least one of the 9 studies will reject the null hypothesis at a 5% significance level?"

My working out is as follows but I'm not sure if my approach is correct. Could someone please help me out?

"Significance level = 5%

P(She rejects the null | no relationship exists) = 0.05

P(She does not reject the null | no relationship exists) = 1-0.05 = 0.95

Number of studies: n = 9

P(At least one is rejected) = 1 - P(None are rejected)

P(None are rejected) = [P(She does not reject the null | no relationship exists)]^9

```
                 = 0.95^9 = 0.63024 (5d.p.)
```

P(At least one is rejected) = 1 - 0.63024

```
                        = 0.36975 (5d.p.) = 36.975%"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct.  The question is framed in terms of multiple hypothesis tests (familywise Type I error control), but in fact, it is nothing more than a question in elementary probability.

If any single test has a Type I error of $\alpha = 0.05$, then the chance that all $9$ independent tests will not reject the null when the null is true is simply $(1 - 0.05)^9$.  Consequently, the probability that at least one of the tests will incorrectly reject the null is $1 - (1 - 0.05)^9$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not sure what you mean by 'incorrectly rejecting the null.' The question just asks the probability that at least one study rejects the null, not necessarily whether it incorrectly or correctly rejects it. Would my working still be correct?

Comment: @Spartasporter Incorrectly rejecting the null = reject $H_0$, given that $H_0$ is true.  The question is asking, "assuming there is no relationship between early childhood education and graduate earnings..." this is the null hypothesis.  So you are assuming that the null is true.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the explanation;.